# RStudio does not show Plotly plots when offline

Tags: r, offline, plotly

Plotly in RStudio sometimes has trouble working off-line, i.e. when no internet connection is available.

Running below script produces no errors in RStudio, but the Viewer remains empty. Clicking on the `Show in new window` icon opens the plot in Chrome without a problem though.

```
rm(list = ls()) # Clear all variables and data
library(plotly)
attach(mtcars)
p <- plot_ly()%>%
    add_trace(data = mtcars, x = ~hp, y = ~mpg,
                     type = "scatter", mode = "lines")
print(p)
```

When I right click on the Viewer and choose `Inspect element` I see the following error in the console:

`Failed to load resource: The internet connection appears to be offline.  http://localhost:29217/session/viewhtmlaf0667b0fcf7/index.html?viewer_pane=1`

Again, opening that link in my browser produces no error.

To work around this I can connect with the internet. After that the plots do show up, even if I disconnect again.
However, this workaround is not always possible due to the lack of internet at some locations.

> My setup is as follows:
>    - MacBook Pro 5,3
>    - OS X 10.11.6
>    - RStudio 1.0.136
>    - Plotly v4.5.6

Comment: Are you behind a proxy that RStudio doesn't know about(ie the proxy is set in the browser but not as an environment variable)?

Comment: I am not behind a proxy. If I check the setting in Chrome it says `Google Chrome is using your computer's system proxy settings to connect to the network.` Checking my system proxy settings I see that there are no proxies configured. However, why would that matter in an offline (no wifi, no ethernet) environment? Do I require an internet connection to run plotly?

Comment: No, you don't need an internet connection to run it, after all it's on localhost.  I was unable to curl my localhost today because of corporate proxy settings. Thought it might be similar. In my case, the proxy redirects all http requests to 'verify' that it's acceptable. If you are in a corporate environment, usually the setting can be found in Internet Options in IE.

Comment: @waterling thanks for thinking with me. I am not in a corporate environment, so it does not apply to me.